# Can F1 students in the US earn Social Security work credits?

Tags: united-states, retirement, international, social-security, f1-student-visa

Assume a typical F1 student in the US. No side gig, focusing on their PhD work, getting a stipend from their school and possibly doing summer internships using CPT. Can they earn [Social Security work credits](https://www.ssa.gov/benefits/retirement/planner/credits.html)? (e.g., can the stipend be used to earn Social Security work? Can the CPT summer internships income be used to earn Social Security work? etc.)

Answer (score 2):

> Can they earn Social Security work credits? (e.g., can the stipend be used to earn Social Security work?

F1 and J1 visa holders who are not US residents for tax purposes are also [exempt from FICA](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-student-liability-for-social-security-and-medicare-taxes) taxes. If they don't pay the FICA taxes they also don't earn the associated credits. See details at the IRS site linked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [link](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-student-liability-for-social-security-and-medicare-taxes) given in [littleadv](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/2998/littleadv)'s [answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/153584/5656), from my understanding, the two options for F1 students in the US earn Social Security work credits are (assuming they keep their F1 visa):

> 1. The exemption does not apply to employment not allowed by USCIS or to employment not closely connected to the purpose for which the visa was issued.
> 2. The exemption does not apply to F-1, 1, or M-1 students who become resident aliens.

Option 1 sounds like it may be against the F1 visa conditions. For option 2, typically an F1 student becomes a resident alien after 5 years:

> Generally, foreign students in F-1, J-1, or M-1 nonimmigrant status who have been in the United States more than 5 calendar years become resident aliens for U.S. tax purpose if they meet the “[Substantial Presence Test](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/substantial-presence-test)” and are liable for Social Security and Medicare taxes. (unless they are exempt from FICA under the "[student FICA exemption](https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/student-exception-to-fica-tax)".